# How to emulate native CREATE response

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to emulate the type of JSON response I get from a ModelSerializer when doing a GET. I have this ViewSet:

```
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.objects.create(
        base_ingredient=Ingredient.objects.get(pk=request.data['base_ingredient']),
        recipe=Recipe.objects.get(pk=request.data['recipe'])
    )
     data = serializers.serialize('json', [recipe_ingredient, ])
     struct = json.loads(data)
     data = json.dumps(struct[0])
     return Response(data)
```

This returns a JSON the physical recipe_ingredient instance instead of just the data like it would with my RecipeIngredientSerializer when I make a GET request.

Once I have created an object through .create(), how can I return a JSON that would have all the same serialization as my RecipeIngredientSerialzer returns when I do a GET?

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this. Why don't you just actually use the RecipeIngredientSerialzer?

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work. I went back and tried now and it worked perfectly. Thanks @DanielRoseman.